# How to correctly implement Sequelize.js in a MEAN-stack based app?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mean-stack

i have a MEAN.js based app, and now i need (at the behest of the cleint)to use MySQL instead of MongoDB. i understand that Sequelize is the way to go.

but searching around for some easy to implement solution didnt bare much fruit, im new to node.js and server side programming.

i need a step by step instruction on how to implement Sequelize in an existing MEAN.js stack that would fit to the existing architecture

Comment: I don't think there's an "easy" solution. You'll need to recreate the schemas/models, import the data from MongoDB to MySQL. Sequelize has a [basic express tutorial in their old docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/) which could be useful. Else there's the current [Getting Started guide](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mean-stack-relational. It comes with sequelize.

[Mean Stack Relational](https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational)

Comment: i ended up merging between mean stack relational and the regular mean-stack, simply copied the sequelize part over the mongoose.. not the most proffesional way but hey, it worked! so thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to join this conversation but thinking my reply could help new google crawlers/ solution seekers. You can try [SEANjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sean), it could help, nearly perfect but needs contribution for Yeoman's auto generators of sub-modules.

SEANjs allows you to use Sequelize for your MySQL or Postgre database. While mean-stack-relational (mentioned in previous comment) provides MVC app architecture, SEANjs follows Modules architecture which resembles the latest MEAN stack 4.2, at time of this writing.